# Gulp bower main losing itself

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower

My code as:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');  
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

var filterByExtension = function(extension){  
    return filter(function(file){
        return file.path.match(new RegExp('.' + extension + '$'));
    });
};

gulp.task('third', function(){  
    var mainFiles = mainBowerFiles();

    if(!mainFiles.length){
        // No main files found. Skipping....
        return;
    }

    var jsFilter = filterByExtension('js');

    return gulp.src(mainFiles)
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(concat('third-party.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
        .pipe(filterByExtension('css'))
        .pipe(concat('third-party.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});
```

Errors here "return file.path.match(new RegExp('.' + extension + '$'))", but this should work. Any suggestions?

Thanks much.

Comment: Does it say what the error is?

Comment: @Mark did the answer solve the issue? If so, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the return type inside your filter function. NodeJS and especially Gulp are extremely picky on which types you pass through the pipe. You need only one unexpected return to break the chain.

According to gulp-filter, your nested filter should return a boolean, and `String.prototype.match` will return an array of matching results or null if there is no match. That's enough to break the thing because it doesn't expect an array.

You can either use `RegExp.prototype.test` which returns a boolean, or check if `match(...).length > 0`. One possible fix:

**JS:**

```
var filterByExtension = function(extension){  
    return filter(function(file){
        var matches = file.path.match(new RegExp('.' + extension + '$'));
        return matches && matches.length > 0;
    });
};
```